# Show HTML captured in variable in an http.get request in an ionic1 view with Angular

Tags: angularjs, ajax, http, ionic-framework

I have a problem when tryintg to draw an HTML page captured in an HTTP request with Angular in an ion-view.

My controller code:

```
app.controller('MiNegocioCtrl', function ($scope, ajax, $sce) {
    ajax.sendApiRequest({}, "GET", url, true).then(function (response) {
        $scope.data = response.data;

        console.log(response.data);
        var negocio = angular.element("#negocio");
        negocio.html(response.data);
    }, function (error) {
        _showPopUp('error', 'error');

    });
})
```

My view code:

```
<ion-view title="Negocio" id="page10">
    <ion-content>
        <div id="negocio" style="width: 100%;height: 100%"></div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope to help you with my answer below:

```
// In your controller, inject the $sce service, and mark the HTML as "trusted":
.controller('MiNegocioCtrl', function($scope, $http, $sce) {
  $scope.data = "";

// make request with service $http
  $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
    $scope.data = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data);
  });

})
```

Your view. Use directive **ng-bind-html**.

```
<ion-view title="Negocio" id="page10">

  <ion-content>
      <div ng-bind-html="data" style="width: 100%;height: 100%"></div>
  </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

Comment: So thanks but i have the same error!!! i was testing that code!! @Andrei